# Prevent the creation of certain tags in TinyMCE on the server and user side

Tags: javascript, html, django, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE plug in to create a text editor. The thing is, I want my users to control the positioning, weight, and list/no list of their document, but not font, font-color, or font-size. I'm looking for a TinyMCE property which will stop the program from adding those tags to the css. Also, I need to implement this on the server side. I'm using django, so is there any function that will do that as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may specify exactly which HTML tags and related attributes are allowed using 'valid_elements' configuration setting:
  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

Answer (score -1):

I believe that as long as you don't provide the buttons for font-related stuff (using the theme_advanced_buttons_1/2/3 parameters), and also don't give them the HTML button, the users won't be able to change fonts/color/etc.

But if they were to paste in some text created elsewhere, which happens to be HTML, they might still do it.  To get rid of that, you'd probably have to filter what the server receives - I have no insight into any ready-made way to do that.

Comment: If you just copy it from word, it automatically adopts the font and color of the word document.